# How to use Entity Framework 5.0?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

After install EF 5.0, it said:

Successfully installed 'EntityFramework 5.0.0-rc'.
Successfully added 'EntityFramework 5.0.0-rc' to MyWeb.

but my solution has many projects, not only the web project. For example, I have a project MyData which is referenced by MyyWeb. How can use use EF 5.0 in MyData project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the package into each project that needs it. You can do this by right-clicking on each project and selecting Manage packages, or by using the Default Project drop-down inside of the Package Manager Console.

Comment: Yes, it's working. Another question: How to uninstall EF 5.0?

Comment: For more information on how to use NuGet, please refer to [the documentation](http://docs.nuget.org/).